# web config error running asp.net app on Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net, web-config, azure-web-app-service, configurationsection

I am very new to Azure and have deployed a .net application to an Azure web Service over FTP and am getting the below error in the web config at the top line of the section below:

```
 It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. 

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Logout" defaultUrl="~/Home" timeout="120" slidingExpiration="true"/>
</authentication>
```

I have searched online and problem seems to generally come when there are multiple web configs, which isnt the case here. Is there something specific I need to configure in Azure? The application runs fine on local web server.

For additional information the application is in a sub directory in the root and I have added a virtual application in the Azure app portal for the root directory of the application.

Comment: Did you modify the `MachineToApplication`setting in your web.config?

Comment: @GeorgeChen There is no MachineToApplication setting in the web.config

Comment: Have you set the web.config in the root folder?